# How to deactivte\close an Amazon AWS user (or at least the billing)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing

I had last semester a university course where I used AWS to do the homework, and later I deleted all instances, all volumes, everything. But it for some reason still counts hours (for now without charging me).
But I would like to know how can I disable every possibility to get charged, just in case I forgot something (cannot find something)
As stated I don't want to use their services anymore, so a brute-force account delete\disable is the best option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just contact AWS and request them to close it.

https://aws.amazon.com/support/

Comment: They replied that they cannot do it for policy reasons, but sent me a link where a few clicks did the job :)